# Do I need an IDP in Sweden

Tags: us-citizens, car-rentals, driving-licenses, sweden

From what I've read, an IDP is not needed for US residents when visiting Sweden. However, there was some indication that an IDP might be needed when renting a car. Is there any definitive answer to whether an IDP is needed to rent in Sweden for a US citizen? Maybe I should contact the specific rental location / bring one just to be safe?

I also see that I need to have had my US license for at least 2 years. This is not a problem; I've had a license for 7. However, I renewed it a little over a year ago. I assume they look at more than the "issued" date on the card?

I'm 25. I will be renting for 3 days.

Edit: I called the specific place that I will be renting at and they told me that I do not need an IDP.

Comment: European/EU format licenses also show the date you initially passed the exam. Is there something like that on yours?

Comment: @Relaxed There is no "initially licensed" indication.  Just the date issued, which is usually done for 4 years.

Comment: @Relaxed Sorry, afk for lunch. What Karlson said is true. There is no "initially licensed" date. My card is issued for 6 years though, so that's slightly different.

Comment: @Karlson New York is issuing 8-year licenses these days, or at least they were six years ago.

Comment: @phoog Most states don't to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Karlson I agree. In addition to NY, I have held licenses from 4 states plus DC, and IIRC one gave me a 5-year license, and four gave me 4-year licenses. I mainly wanted to make the point that it varies from state to state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer in your case is, **no you don't need one**

Unlike some countries Sweden [doesn't require](https://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/overseas/idp-requirements-by-country.html#V) you to have an IDP before you can drive there, however you do need a valid license to drive and in case yours had been in a language other than [English](http://www.swedenroadtrip.com/renting-a-car/) (*see Requirements section*) you'd [need to have an IDP](http://www.swedenroadtrip.com/driving-in-sweden/drivers-license/), which is just a translation of your national driving license.

Answer (score 1):

As a holder of a non-EEA licence, you **do not** need an IDP **if and only if** your license is in English, German or French.

Meaning, you will **not** need one.

Comment: What if your license is not in one of those three languages but is a common-format EU license?

Comment: Your nationality is completely irrelevant here. Important is the issuing state of the driver's license.

Comment: Absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking when putting it like that. Yes, all EEA licences are valid without an IDP, non-EEA ones only if in English, German or French